# Making LaTeX Beamer Black & White

Tags: latex, pdflatex, beamer

Is there a way to make LaTeX Beamer output black & white? I need it for paper printing purposes. I'm using the default color theme, and for contrast reasons I need the title and everything to be black. If there is a black&white color scheme, I could use it, but otherwise I don't want other color schemes, with colored backgrounds. Maybe there are some commands which I can redefine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, you can change the color of all elements of your beamer theme using `\setbeamercolor`. You can use fg for changing the foreground and bg for the background. The problem of this is that you cannot use the traditional rbg scheme and you have to make very strange combinations of colors with a not-very-friendly way of giving the shares of each color you want to combine

Answer (score 10):

You can also just add `gray` option to `documentclass` declaration:

```
\documentclass[gray]{beamer}
...
```

Answer (score 6):

OK, found it after some more search. The answer is:

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `\selectcolormodel{gray}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\selectcolormodel{gray}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```